# DetailsView edit and new buttons don't change the mode of the DetailsView

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, detailsview

I'm trying to code a DetailsView but have some coding missing. Can you look at this coding and let me know what I'm missing because clicking on the Edit button or the New button will not change the mode of the DetailsView so I can enter data into it.

This is the coding for the DetailsView:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel 
    ID="UpdatePanelParentsSummary" 
    runat="server" 
    UpdateMode="Conditional">

    <ContentTemplate> 
        <asp:DetailsView 
            ID="DetailsViewParentsDetails" 
            runat="server" 
            Height="50px" 
            Width="404px"
            AutoGenerateRows="False">

            <Fields>
                <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">

                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button 
                            ID="ButtonEdit" 
                            runat="server" 
                            CausesValidation="False" 
                            CommandName="Edit" 
                            Text="Edit" />

                        &nbsp;
                        <asp:Button 
                            ID="ButtonNew" 
                            runat="server" 
                            CausesValidation="False" 
                            CommandName="New" 
                            Text="New" />

                        &nbsp;
                        <asp:Button 
                            ID="ButtonDelete" 
                            runat="server" 
                            CausesValidation="False" 
                            CommandName="Delete" 
                            Text="Delete" />

                            <AjaxToolKit:ConfirmButtonExtender ID="deleteButtonConfirmation" 
                                runat="server" 
                                ConfirmText='<%# "You are about to remove: " & vbcr & 
                                    Eval("FatherName") & vbcr & Eval("MotherName") & "!!!" &
                                    vbcrlf & "Are you sure you want to do this?" & vbcrlf &
                                    "Clicking the OK button will delete this parent." %>'
                                Enabled="True" 
                                TargetControlID="ButtonDelete">

                            </AjaxToolKit:ConfirmButtonExtender>
                    </ItemTemplate>

                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button 
                            ID="ButtonUpdate" 
                            runat="server" 
                            CausesValidation="True" 
                            CommandName="Update" 
                            Text="Update" />

                        &nbsp;
                        <asp:Button 
                            ID="ButtonCancelUpdates" 
                            runat="server" 
                            CausesValidation="False" 
                            CommandName="Cancel" 
                            Text="Cancel" />
                    </EditItemTemplate>

                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button 
                            ID="ButtonInsert" 
                            runat="server" 
                            CausesValidation="True" 
                            CommandName="Insert" 
                            Text="Insert" />

                        &nbsp;
                        <asp:Button 
                            ID="ButtonCancelInsert" 
                            runat="server" 
                            CausesValidation="False" 
                            CommandName="Cancel" 
                            Text="Cancel" />
                    </InsertItemTemplate>

                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" 
                    ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" Visible="False" />

                <asp:BoundField 
                    DataField="FatherName" 
                    HeaderText="Father's Name:">

                    <ItemStyle ForeColor="Blue" />
                </asp:BoundField>

                <asp:BoundField 
                    DataField="MotherName" 
                    HeaderText="Mother's Name:">

                    <ItemStyle ForeColor="Blue" />
                </asp:BoundField>

                <asp:BoundField 
                    DataField="FatherOccupation" 
                    HeaderText="Father's Occupation:">

                    <ItemStyle ForeColor="Blue" />
                </asp:BoundField>

                <asp:BoundField 
                    DataField="FatherEmploymentPlace" 
                    HeaderText="Father's Employment Place:">

                    <ItemStyle ForeColor="Blue" />
                </asp:BoundField>

                <asp:BoundField 
                    DataField="FatherWorkPhone" 
                    HeaderText="Father's Work Phone:">

                    <ItemStyle ForeColor="Blue" />
                </asp:BoundField>

            </Fields>

            <HeaderTemplate>
                <%#IIf(Eval("FatherName") = Nothing,
                    "Adding New Student", "Details For: " & Eval("FatherName") & " *** " & Eval("MotherName"))%>             
            </HeaderTemplate>
        </asp:DetailsView>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Remove the UpdatePanel to find the error by your self - update panel is hide the errors inside javascript throws that you can only view if you open the javascript console

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried removing the UpdatePanel but the buttons still don't put the DetailsView into edit or new mode. There are no error messages, only the mode never changes like the buttons are not doing anything. I don't know Java so the Javascript would not help me. Could you tell me what additional coding I missed? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the OnItemCommand event handler to your DetailsView.

```
<asp:DetailsView 
        ID="DetailsViewParentsDetails" 
        OnItemCommand="DetailsViewParentsDetails_ItemCommand"
        runat="server" 
        Height="50px" 
        Width="404px"
        AutoGenerateRows="False">
```

In your code-behind file (.cs), you will need to add the following:

```
protected void DetailsViewParentsDetails_ItemCommand(object sender, DetailsViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName.Equals("New"))
    {
         this.DetailsViewParentsDetails.ChangeMode(DetailsViewMode.Insert);
         this.DetailsViewParentsDetails.DataBind();
    }
    else if (e.CommandName.Equals("Edit"))
    {
         this.DetailsViewParentsDetails.ChangeMode(DetailsViewMode.Edit);
         this.DetailsViewParentsDetails.DataBind();
    }
}
```

[MSDN doc on DetailsView.ItemCommand - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview.itemcommand(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview.itemcommand%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)